# Removing Annoying Delay in optirun

Tags: 12.04, performance, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

Can I somehow remove the ~4 seconds delay present in calls to optirun? I need my compiler-run iterations to run faster. Does bumblebeed play a role in this?

I'm sitting on Ubuntu 12.04 on an ASUS X53S with NVIDIA GEFORCE GT 630M.

Answer (score 8):

That delay is caused by the time that is necessary for starting the secondary X server. If you do not need to preserve power, I suggest you to change `KeepUnusedXServer=false` to `KeepUnusedXServer=true` in `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. After doing so, restart the BUmblebee daemon with `sudo restart bumblebeed`. Now, only the initial start takes some time, but further use of the card is instant.

Alternatively you can keep another program using `optirun` so that the X server is not shutdown after each run of `optirun`. I use it like:

```
optirun bash
```

(in a different shell):

```
optirun program-that-is-tested
```

When done, I can close the `optirun` shell by typing `exit`.